# cx_Freeze does not add shortcut to startup folder on installation

Tags: python-3.x, windows-installer, shortcut, cx-freeze

I'm trying to add a shortcut to the startup folder using cx_Freeze when the user runs the .msi installer. Currently, it adds a shortcut to the desktop, but not to the startup folder. I have checked both the `shell:startup` folder and the `shell:common startup` folder, along with running a full PC check for the shortcut. I also tried doing only one shortcut in the shortcut table (going to the startup folder) but that also seems to direct to the desktop (along with the start menu property)

```
"Program to build project into exexutable and installer"
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os.path

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

shortcut_table = [
    ("DesktopShortcut",        # Shortcut
     "DesktopFolder",          # Directory_
     "program",           # Name
     "TARGETDIR",              # Component_
     "[TARGETDIR]main.exe",# Target
     None,                     # Arguments
     None,                     # Description
     None,                     # Hotkey
     "icon.ico",                     # Icon
     None,                     # IconIndex
     None,                     # ShowCmd
     'TARGETDIR'               # WkDir
     ),

     ("StartupShortcut",        # Shortcut
     "StartupFolder",          # Directory_
     "program",           # Name
     "TARGETDIR",              # Component_
     "[TARGETDIR]main.exe",# Target
     None,                     # Arguments
     None,                     # Description
     None,                     # Hotkey
     "icon.ico",                     # Icon
     None,                     # IconIndex
     None,                     # ShowCmd
     'TARGETDIR'               # WkDir
     ),
    ]

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32": base = "Win32GUI"

msi_data = {"Shortcut": shortcut_table}
bdist_msi_options = {'data': msi_data}

executables = [Executable("main.py", shortcutName='MQTTStatus', shortcutDir='DesktopFolder', icon='icon.ico', base=base)]

setup(
    name = 'MQTTStatus',
    author = 'Ethan Armstrong',
    options={
        "build_exe": {
            "packages":["paho.mqtt.client", "time", "json", "ast", "os", "sys"],
            "include_files":["icon.ico", "data.txt"]
            }},
    executables = executables,
    version = "1.2"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `Executable` arguments `shortcutName='MQTTStatus', shortcutDir='DesktopFolder'` cause `bdist_msi` to overwrite the shortcut table you have manually set, try to remove these arguments.

EDIT: And, of course, you also need to pass the `bdist_msi` options in the `setup` call:

```py
setup(
    name = 'MQTTStatus',
    author = 'Ethan Armstrong',
    options={
        "build_exe": {
            "packages":["paho.mqtt.client", "time", "json", "ast", "os", "sys"],
            "include_files":["icon.ico", "data.txt"]
            },
        "bdist_msi": bdist_msi_options
        },
    executables = executables,
    version = "1.2"
)
```